# Chrome freezes after using youtube for certain time

Tags: google-chrome, freeze, youtube

Whenever I am watching YouTube it freezes Google Chrome after some time. The video keeps on playing without any lag or buffers but rest of things like subtitles just freeze and if I try to exit the full screen mode then it gets stuck in between full screen and the normal small screen mode. And then I have to minimize the whole google chrome and open it back.

I've tried clean installing Windows 10 and Windows 11 but it didn't work.

My laptop has a Ryzen 4600H and Nvidia GTX 1650. So, I am quite sure it is not happening because of specs.

What's going on? How can I fix this?
TIA!

Comment: I would try disabling hardware acceleration within Chrome.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. thanks